# $f:X\to Y$ is injective iff $f(X-A)$ is a subset of $Y-f(A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$f:X\to Y$ is injective iff $f(X-A)$ is a subset of $Y-f(A)$
how are you able to show that this holds for X,Y sets and A is any subset of X.

Comment: I am struggling mainly with the <= direction

Answer (score 1):

To be clear the statement is that "$f:X \to Y$ is injective" and "$f(X-A) \subseteq Y-f(A)$ **for all subsets $A$ of $X$**" are equivalent.

Suppose $f$ is injective. Fix an arbitrary subset $A$ of $X$. If $x \in X-A$ then $f(x) \notin f(A)$ (otherwise there would exist some $a \in A$ such that $f(x)=f(a)$, contradicting injectivity). Thus $x \in Y - f(A)$.

Suppose $f$ is not injective. We want to produce some subset $A \subseteq X$ such that $f(X-A) \not\subseteq Y - f(A)$. Since $f$ is not injective, there exist $x \ne x'$ in $X$ such that $f(x)=f(x')$. Let $A = \{x\}$. Then $x' \in X-A$ but $f(x') = f(x) \in f(A)$ so $x' \notin Y - f(A)$.

Comment: Why is the last paragraph necessary

Comment: The last paragraph is the $\impliedby$ direction (or rather, its contrapositive).

Comment: Always forget proof by contra position.

Comment: How do you find these things so easy. How many years practice do you have?

Comment: @Anteater23 If you keep working hard, there will be a time where this looks simple (just as there are other mathematical concepts you have learned before that seem easy to you now).

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I become lecturer one day. My lecturer is passionate and an inspiration to me,