# Relationship between $f(X - A)$ and $Y - f(A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> For $A \subset X$, we define $f(A)$ to be the subset of $Y$ consisting of all elements $y \in Y$ for which there exists $x \in A$ with $f(x) = y$. How does $f(X - A)$ compare with $Y - f(A)$?

It seems to me that there may be no relationship or the subset relation could be in either or both directions.

If $y \in f(X - A)$, then $y =   f(x)$ for some $x \in X - A$. But $f$ may not be injective, so we could also have $y = f(t)$ for some $t \in A$, so $f(X - A) \not \subset Y - f(A)$ if $y$ has two such preimages. If $f$ is injective, then $y = f(x)$ uniquely for some $x \in X - A$. So $y \not \in f(A)$, hence $y \in Y - f(A)$, so $f(X - A) \subset Y - f(A)$.

If $y \in Y - f(A)$, then $y \not \in f(A)$, but $f$ may not be surjective and $y$ may not even be in the image of $f$, so there's no guarantee that $y$ be in the image of $X - A$. If $f$ we re surjective, then $y = f(x)$, and since $x \not \in A$, $x \in X - A$, so $y \in f(X - A)$ and $Y - f(A) \subset f(X - A)$.

So my conclusion based on this is: if $f$ is injective, $f(X - A) \subset Y - f(A)$. If $f$ is surjective, $Y - f(A) \subset f(X - A)$. So if $f$ is bijective, $f(X - A) = Y - f(A)$. I'm not able to tell whether these are biconditional statements, but I believe they are.

Comment: you can see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393970/fx-to-y-is-injective-iff-fx-a-is-a-subset-of-y-fa your arguments are correct

Comment: Your arguments seems to be correct. In general, $f(X)\setminus f(A)\subset f(X\setminus A)$.